# Sharing Tableau Dashboards With A Large Team

Tags: r, shiny, tableau-api

I am evaluating an affordable solution to share the dashboard visualizations I create with *Tableau Desktop* with a team of about 100 people.

While the license cost of $2,000 for *Tableau Desktop Professional* (my data sources are disparate - Postgres, Oracle, BigQuery) is affordable, sharing the dashboards with 100 other people using *Tableau Online* will cost $500 * 100 = $50,000/yr and that is prohibitively expensive. *Tableau Server* looks even more expensive with $10,000 for the first 10 users. So neither of these solutions is good.

I really love using Tableau in the data discovery process. Most of the time my job is to just find something interesting in the data. I usually do not have specific questions in the beginning.

I want to get inputs on whether my line of thinking is correct here. I am considering getting just one license for *Tableau Desktop* for $2,000 and do the data discoveries and explorations on my own machine. Once the process is complete and visualizations are finalized, I am thinking of translating what I did in *Tableau Desktop* into R code and then build a web app with Shiny to share with the team. Is this a sensible approach? Or are there better approaches to this problem?

PS: Some of the dashboards are with real-time data, so I cannot do any offline data dump from Tableau and use it to share with others.

Comment: Note that Shiny Server open source edition is single-threaded (see https://www.rstudio.com/faq-items/shiny-server-can-one-user-interact-application-concurrently-request-wait-prior-users-request-complete/) , so if you have multiple people using it in the same time, and your data analysis/visualization code is slow, your end user will find the Shiny app extremely slow. If you want the multi-threaded Shiny Server commercial edition, it is currently $9,995 per year. Deploying it on shinyapp.io also costs quite a lot if you have lots of users. Keep that in mind while you search for a solution.

Comment: This is a very valid point. Thx for sharing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is a reasonable approach, though it sounds like a lot of work.

Here are some other approaches:

1. Take recordings and screenshot of yourself illustrating the data in Tableau and embed it in your presentations (PowerPoint, or whatever you like to use).
2. Check out this thread I started a while back on another SE site about [free alternatives to Tableau](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/21028/best-free-alternative-to-tableau). Basically Qlik was the top recommendation.
3. Just [kill Tableau](http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/uninstalling-tableau-desktop). Is it really doing anything for you? They make me use it at work and it just seems to slow me down. Can't you find the same patterns in R just as quickly (with numbers instead of graphs) and then do your Shiny interactive visualizations? I mean even if Tableau doesn't slow you down in general like it does to me, then surely it must slow you down if you're going to have duplicate your work with Shiny?
4. Is the data super secret? If not, I believe you can use [Tableau Public](https://public.tableau.com/s/) freely in unlimited quantity. If it is, you could use fake or cryptic labels for your data and still use Tableu Public.
5. You use Linux, right? Would any of [these alternatives](http://alternativeto.net/software/tableau/?platform=linux) work for you?
6. You mentioned in the comment that you want live updates. What if you just automatically refresh your reports and visualizations, storing each copy? I've been doing this for years. A daily refresh is rarely less insightful than a live connection. When I use Linux I do it with cron jobs. In Windows I use task scheduler.
7. [Plotly](https://plot.ly/) is very popular.
8. If your company really needs this functionality, doesn't that mean that the benefit is greater than the cost? If so, then download the [free trial](http://www.tableau.com/products/server) of Tableau Server (or Pro, or whatever you need) and use it to convince your company that you need the software and get them to buy it.
9. Maybe [d3](https://d3js.org/) would do the trick?
10. Become [romantically involved](http://www.wikihow.com/Seduce-a-Woman) with a Tableau employee and get her to give you free licenses.
11. [Contact Tableau](http://www.tableau.com/about/contact) and tell them your problem. Believe it or not, they will almost certainly help. They will be very eager to keep you as their advocate inside of their company, so they will surely offer extensions to free trials, help convincing your bosses to purchase it, and understanding your position will likely lower the price they're willing to accept in negotiations.
12. [Negotiate a business partnership](http://smallbiztrends.com/2012/06/how-to-negotiate-a-partnership-agreement.html) with Tableau to get their products free in exchange for your goods or services.

Comment: Option 1 is not useful in my case, since I need live updates. Option 2: Qlik  seems to be a Windows-only desktop client and nobody uses Windows in my company :-(. 3: Tableau doesn't slow me down, but doing the same thing in R will, though it should get faster with time. 4: Yes, data can't be made public

Comment: @arun Ah. It is quite a conundrum. I will see if I can think of anything else, but as you evaluate the problem keep in mind that Tableau is a relatively new tool, so perhaps some of the perceived need for all of its high priced features isn't really a need, because the whole world got along fine without it until recently. Also, some people like me have access to Tableau Professional and Tableau Server and just absolutely *hate* this piece of software...   Oh hey I found something else http://alternativeto.net/software/tableau/?platform=linux

Comment: @arun I added 8 more suggestions

Comment: Thx for the answers, but I guess SO was the wrong place to ask this.

Comment: @arun Sure. You might get different / more answers from Data Science or Superuser. I don't think #10 can fail though.

Comment: Two months later, I am actually doing your suggestion (3), since my company was taking forever to decide which tool to buy! And I do not regret the time spent learning and developing with R, ggplot2 and Shiny :-) For now, the load on the web app is minimal, so I am fine with the free Shiny version.

Comment: @arun I was actually just thinking about this yesterday and wondering what the outcome was. Glad to hear it worked out. :)